# Javascript array of headers to a tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, tree

I'm working with a list of HTML headers (h2,h3,h4,h5,h6).
The picture describes the idea: [image: some nested headers]

```
[
    {
        text: 'Some header',
        rank: 2, // stays for <h2>
    },
    {
        text: 'Some another header',
        rank: 3, // stays for <h3>
    },
    {
        text: 'A header with the same rank',
        rank: 3, // stays for <h3>
    },
    {
        text: 'One more subsection header',
        rank: 4, // stays for <h4>
    }
]
```

And I'm trying to turn it into a tree:

```
[
    {
        text: 'Some header',
        children: [
            {
                text: 'Some another header',
            },
            {
                text: 'A header with the same rank',
                children: [
                    {
                        text: 'One more subsection header',
                    }
                ]
             }
         ]
     }
]
```

Here's my current code:

```
            function list_to_tree(list) {
                // We go from the end to the beggining
                list = list.reverse();

                let node, nextNode, roots = [], i;

                for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
                    node = list[i];
                    nextNode = list[i+1];

                    // If the next one's rank is greater, the current into the next as a child
                    if (nextNode !== undefined && node.rank > nextNode.rank) {
                        list[i+1].children.push(node);
                    } else {
                    // Else it's a root
                        roots.push(node);
                    }
                }

                return roots;
            };
```

But it works only for the first h3, but the second h3 will go as a root. Any idea on how to achieve the goal? Thank you.

Comment: why the rank4 is under the last rank3

Comment: @xianshenglu, "One more subsection header" is a subtopic of a "A header with the same rank". This picture describes the idea https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-d9389403ab1cc626cf27ed3b966dff38

Comment: what should happens with more data? or is it just a linear nesting?

Comment: @NinaScholz look at this picture please https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-d9389403ab1cc626cf27ed3b966dff38 , I have it as a simple array with h{x} data, but need to make a nested array where all underlying h3 are children of h2, underlying h4 are children of parent h3, etc.

Comment: where do you have the information of `<h1>`?

Comment: this is not a good question because you didn't think about more complicated situation as your picture gave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the level property `rank` for indicating the nested position in a helper array.

Then iterate the data and build children arrays, if necessary.

```js
function getTree(array) {
    var levels = [{}];
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        levels.length = o.rank;
        levels[o.rank - 1].children = levels[o.rank - 1].children || [];
        levels[o.rank - 1].children.push(o);
        levels[o.rank] = o;
    });
    return levels[0].children;
}

var data = [{ text: 'Main Heading', rank: 1 }, { text: 'Sub Heading', rank: 2 }, { text: 'Sub Sub Heading', rank: 3 }, { text: 'Sub Heading', rank: 2 }, { text: 'Sub Sub Heading', rank: 3 }, { text: 'Sub Sub Heading', rank: 3 }];

console.log(getTree(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Good answer in relation to the question - worth noting when the data doesn't start at rank 1, has missing rank levels or is unordered it will throw `Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`. My use case scrapes all headings out of the DOM and on some bad pages heading levels may have been skipped which causes this problem.

Comment: Does anyone know how to modify this to allow "skipping" levels? Ie. you can have rank 2 headings without rank 1 headings.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work irrespective of starting rank and also of the order in which the list is given... and it uses the exact data you provided...

```js
var jsonHeaders =
[
    {
        text: 'Some header',
        rank: 2, // stays for <h2>
    },
    {
        text: 'Some another header',
        rank: 3, // stays for <h3>
    },
    {
        text: 'A header with the same rank',
        rank: 3, // stays for <h3>
    },
    {
        text: 'One more subsection header',
        rank: 4, // stays for <h4>
    }
];

function list_to_tree(list)
{
    var jsonTree = [{}];
    list = list.reverse();

    for (i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        node = list[i];
        var json = {};
        json.text = node.text;
        json.rank = node.rank;
        
        if(jsonTree[0].rank == undefined)
        {
            jsonTree[0] = json;
        }
        else
        if(jsonTree[0].rank == json.rank)
        {
            jsonTree.push(json);
        }
        else
        if(jsonTree[0].rank < json.rank)
        {
            jsonTree[0] = ranker(jsonTree[0], json);
        }
        else
        if(jsonTree[0].rank > json.rank)
        {
            var jsonTemp = jsonTree[0];
            jsonTree[0]  = json;
            json         = jsonTemp;

            jsonTree[0] = ranker(jsonTree[0], json);
        }
    }
    return jsonTree;
}

function ranker(jsonTree, json)
{
    if(jsonTree.children == undefined)
    {
        jsonTree.children = [];
        jsonTree.children.push(json);
    }
    else
    if(jsonTree.children[0].rank == json.rank)
    {
        jsonTree.children.push(json);
    }
    else
    if(jsonTree.children[0].rank < json.rank)
    {
        jsonTree.children[0] = ranker(jsonTree.children[0], json);
    }
    else
    if(jsonTree.children[0].rank > json.rank)
    {
        var jsonTemp = jsonTree;
        jsonTree     = json;
        json         = jsonTemp;

        jsonTree.children[0] = ranker(jsonTree.children[0], json);
    }
    return jsonTree;
}

var jsonTree = list_to_tree(jsonHeaders);
console.log('jsonArrayTree = ', jsonTree);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working function in case someone needs it:

```
            function list_to_tree(list) {
                list = list.reverse();

                let node, currentRank = list[0].rank, i, roots = [];

                for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
                    node = list[i];

                    if (node.rank > currentRank) {

                        for (let n = i; n < list.length; n += 1) {
                            if (list[n].rank < node.rank) {
                                list[n].children.unshift(node);
                                break;
                            }
                        }


                    } else {
                        currentRank = node.rank;
                        roots.push(node);
                    }
                }

                return roots.reverse();
            };
```